# How to use the animation trigger from separate .ts file in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, animation

There is an [example](https://angular.io/guide/reusable-animations) of exporting an animation trigger in Angular:

```
import { animation, style, animate, trigger, transition, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';
export const triggerAnimation = trigger('openClose', [
  transition('open => closed', [
    useAnimation(transitionAnimation, {
      params: {
        height: 0,
        opacity: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        time: '1s'
      }
    })
  ])
]);
```

But I can't figure out how do I use it in my component. There is the useAnimation() method bun no methods like useTrigger() or something like it.

How to use the animation trigger from separate .ts file in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would use any other animation, as listed in the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/animations). Basically you add your animation within the `@Component`

The only difference is that you have to import the one that was defined in different module, e.g.

```
import { triggerAnimation } from 'path-to-your-file-with-animations'

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
      animations: [
        triggerAnimation
      ]
    })
```